# How to get the switch toggle switch current state(true/false) onload in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a multiple switch toggle which is coming from PHP/Mysql code, I want to show the **div** in that toggle which is currently **ON**.

Also, I want to show/hide div when that toggle switch on/off

[image]

My Php Code:

```
  <li>
    <?php echo $_ship_method_value['shipping_title'];?>
    <label class="switch">
      <!-- Toggled Case -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggd" name="toggle" value="<? echo $_ship_method_value['shipping_id']; ?>" class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' data-switchery <? if(array_key_exists("shipping_available",$_ship_method_value)) echo 'checked'; ?> /> 
       <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
  </li>

      <div class="show-hide">
         <p>Want to show this div ;-)</p>
     </div>
```

My jQuery Code

```
   $('input[name=toggle]').change(function(){
          var mode = $(this).prop('checked');
            if(mode == true){
              $(".show-hide").show();
            }else{
              $(".show-hide").hide();
            }
          });'
```

but this code is only working on click of toggle for the single toggle event.

Please help me to find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Are you div a sibling of li ?? If it was, it would be `$(this).closest("li").next(".show-hide")`. Also note you can't have a div as a sibling of a li, I suggest you move it into the li, or show us the complete html.

Comment: do you want to show different div for each toggle button or save div for all toggle button

Comment: can you please write your code on codepen?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.toggle_check_box').change(function(){
          var mode = $(this).prop('checked');
            if(mode == true){
              $(".show-hide").show();
            }else{
              $(".show-hide").hide();
            }
          });
```

you can apply class for your checkbox and use like this.. This will toggle div on all switch button

Comment: Hi Deepak, thank you for your reply, but it's not working, .show-hide div showing for all toggle and when I click on any toggle for on/off then it removes from all toggle and appears the same for all when I ON the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('body').on('change', 'input[name=toggle]', function() {
    var mode = $(this).prop('checked');
    if (mode == true) {
        $(".show-hide").show();
    } else {
        $(".show-hide").hide();
    }
});
```

** Update **

If div is located next to li then the bellow code will work for you.

```
 $('body').on('change', 'input[name=toggle]', function() {
    var mode = $(this).prop('checked');
    if (mode == true) {
       $(this).closest("li").next(".show-hide").show();
    } else {
       $(this).closest("li").next(".show-hide").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Hiren, thank you for your reply, but it's not working, .show-hide div showing for all toggle and when I click on any toggle for on/off then it removes from all toggle and appears the same for all when I ON the toggle.

Comment: Please share your HTML with us. Is <div> is next to the <li> tag or located somewhere?

Comment: Hi Hiren, https://codepen.io/alok-kumar-the-typescripter/pen/zYdwbgy

Comment: Please check above code will work for you. I've tested on codepen.

Comment: @AlokKumar You codepen does not have jquery installed and that is why the example didnt work

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I have installed jQuery on codepen , please check now.

Comment: @AlokKumar ,Please check   https://codepen.io/Hirenpatelhv/pen/eYEWozQ

Comment: Hi @HirenPatel, I have checked on my end, it's not working. Same result!

Comment: Initially, you have to set proper CSS, then it will work, as you have set checkbox as checked and not showing the div so how it's work, you need click twice to meet your condition.

Comment: I've updated it. I've initially unchecked all checkboxes and hide all the div and now it's working as you were aspected.